# Евклидово расстояние между двумя числами

Tags: pascal, ассемблер

Есть два 32двух разрядных числа. Старшие 1байт этих чисел всегда 00. Суть, такова, надо найти евклидово расстояние этих чисел побайтно. Ну допустим эти два числа $050703 и $060401. sqrt(($03-$01)^2+($07-$04)^2+($05-$06)^2).

Я написал вот такую функцию:

```
function test(a,b:integer):double; register;
var d:integer;
asm
  mov eax,a
  and eax,$FF
  mov d,eax
  fild d
  mov eax,b
  and eax,$FF
  mov d,eax
  fild d
  fsub
  fld st(0)
  fmul

  mov eax,a
  shr eax,8
  and eax,$FF
  mov d,eax
  fild d
  mov eax,b
  shr eax,8
  and eax,$FF
  mov d,eax
  fild d
  fsub
  fld st(0)
  fmul

  fadd

  mov eax,a
  shr eax,16
  and eax,$FF
  mov d,eax
  fild d
  mov eax,b
  shr eax,16
  and eax,$FF
  mov d,eax
  fild d
  fsub
  fld st(0)
  fmul

  fadd
  fsqrt
end;
```

Сдается мне можно было сделать попроще. Буду благодарен за любые советы.

Comment: Ну вычитание можно было и целое использовать. Да и возведение в квадрат тоже. Вместо трёх кусков можно было сделать в цикле.

И кто же так над молодёжью-то издевается? Евклидово расстояние побайтово...

Comment: Да на самом деле все просто, есть два значения цвета ($BGR) нужно найти их разницу.

Comment: Спасибо, за совет. P.S. Это я сам над собой так издеваюсь)

Answer (score 2):

А ассемблер -- это принципиально?

Делайте проще:

```
var abytes: array[1..4] of byte absolute a;
    bbytes: array[1..4] of byte absolute b;
begin
    result := sqrt(sqr(abytes[1] - bbytes[1]) +
                   sqr(abytes[2] - bbytes[2]) +
                   sqr(abytes[3] - bbytes[3]) +
                   sqr(abytes[4] - bbytes[4]));
end;
```

Comment: @VladD a что будет, если байтики в a будут больше, чем байтики в b? Что насчитает трупный паскаль на sqr((-1) & $FF) ?

Comment: @alexlz: `sqr` -- это квадрат, а не корень.

Comment: > трупный паскаль  
> трупный делфи 
> бла бла бла
как меня радуют такие изречения

Comment: @alexlz: с новым кодом не должно, по идее.

Comment: Ну да, хотелось бы на ассемблере. Тот код который у меня в вопросе, по крайней мере на 20% быстрее работает чем например вот это (сейчас будет длинная формула): 

result:=(sqrt(sqr(byte(a)-byte(b))+sqr(byte(a shr 8)-byte(b shr 8))+sqr(byte(a shr 16)-byte(b shr 16))))

Comment: @Timenzzo: У вас этот код выполняется миллионы раз? Если нет, оптимизация не нужна. Потому что разница в абсолютных единицах будет пара микросекунд, у вас расходы на запуск процесса больше.

Comment: @VladD автор написал, что ему надо определять близость цветов (кстати, @Timenzzo, а зачем извлекать квадратный корень?. Метрика немного другая, более далёкие цвета будут давать большую разность -- ну так и пусть...).

@teanЫЧ где я писал "трупный делфи"? "трупный паскаль" -- несколько искажённое название борландовского продукта "туробопаскаль". Ну так реклама -- она на то и даётся, чтобы над ней смеяться. (Вообще мне трудно представить язык программирования с турбиной. Апокалиптическая картинка). IDE "с крылышками", блин.

Comment: @alexlz, значит я вас не так понял :) Просто все повсюду обсерают паскаль/делфи, называют мертвыми языками/IDE, что на мой взгляд, как минимум, несправедливо. Ведь первые версии Windows, PhotoShop и ид. и тп. были написаны именно на паскале... ЯП-то не мертвый, да он был в упадке, но сейчас за него серьезно взялись Embarcadero.   

ЗЫ. Яндекс по запросу "язык программирования с турбиной" выдает забавные картинки, например барышню, повесившуюся в туалете =/

Comment: @VladD, Ну да довольно часто. Вообщем некий алгоритм кластеризации палитры изображения. Есть некое множество кастомных цветов около 500 штук Uc. Берется изображение, сначала выделяется множество уникальных цветов этого изображения Ui. Потом это множество приводится к множеству кастомных цветов, для каждого цвета из Ui ищется ближайший из Uc, получается подмножество Ur множества Uc. Потом Ur кластеризуется до N цветов. Вобщем изображение из миллионов цветов перегоняется в изображение, состоящее из N цветов, кастомного набора цветов.

Comment: @alexlz, согласен, можно и без извлечения корня.

Comment: @teanЫЧ Оно, конечно, не по теме, и вообще -- холивар, но паскаль мне уже давно не нравится, а паскаль от борланда -- тем более (потому как мутант, и не паскаль, и не си). А вот про то, что Windows и Adobe Photoshop были писаны на паскале -- хотелось бы ссылку. Поскольку транслятора в паскаля от ms я не припомню (MS C -- был, до MS VC++ и MS VS). SDK для виндов был, вроде, начиная с BP7. (Про TP6 я такого как-то не помню).

Comment: Недавно была статья на хабре, в которой автор давал ссылки на выложенный разработчиками паскалевский код фотошопа. Там же (либо в комментариях, либо в самой теме), вроде, был пруфлинк по винде.

Comment: @alexlz: это было ещё под Mac, ЕМНИМС.

Comment: @Timenzzo: хм, а включенная макс. оптимизация не спасает? Уберите квадратный корень, будет существенно быстрее. Подобный простейший код нормальный оптимизатор должен уметь сделать не медленнее ассемблера, закодированного вручную.

Comment: @teanЫЧ вспомните -- публикуйте.

@VladD про мак -- могёт быть. Злые языки утверждали, что именно с маковский Object Pascal Борланд и перелопатил в свой TP с объедками.

Comment: @alexlz, Попробую, но хотелось бы сразу максимум. С ассемблером начал разбираться, вот буквально сегодня узнал про такую штуку как расширение ММХ. Эта штука специально для обработки больших потоков данных, типа обработки изображений, графики, звука и т.д. Пробежался по примерам какие нашел. Там есть именно команды для побайтовой обработки данных. Ну например, самое простое два 32х разрядных числа, складываются побайтово за один такт процессора (по крайней мере так заявлено). Может еще есть какие расширения у процессоров нового поколения. Это довольно давно внедрено.

Answer (score 1):

Решил все-таки использовать такую метрику: |r1-r2|+|b1-b2|+|g1-g2|

Вот такая функция получилась:

```
function testRaz(a,b:integer):integer;
asm
  pxor mm0,mm0
  movd mm1,a
  movd mm2,b
  punpcklbw mm0,mm1
  pxor mm1,mm1
  punpcklbw mm1,mm2
  psadbw mm0,mm1
  movd result,mm0
  emms
end;
```

Хоть это и не является ответом на первоначальный вопрос, но в решении моей задачи, меня устраивает. Авось еще кому-нибудь пригодится.

Всем спасибо за советы!